# Check if an image is the same

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a website that embeds images from Imgur.com and I want a code that will display a custom 404 image if the default imgur error image is displayed.

The error image that I want to check if it's displayed is http://i.imgur.com/ffffffffffff.jpg

Comment: Try and help people help you by providing examples of the images and the URLs...

Comment: You could generate an MD5 of the 404 image file and compare.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? to look if images are the same then if they are the same show the custom 404 image or... you just want to put custom 404 image if one of your images can't load or can't be found

Answer (score 4):

You can hash a files and then compare them:

```
if(md5_file($file1) === md5_file($file2)) 
{
    // the same images
} 
else 
{
    // different images
}
```

You can use a relative or absolute paths.

---

**How to check if the default error image is displayed?**

```
if(md5_file("http://i.imgur.com/ffffffffffff.jpg") === md5_file("http://i.imgur.com/some-other-non-existent-image.jpg"))
{
    //display your error image
}
```

Comment: This is also rumoured to be faster than the `sha1_file()` method on larger files. [PHP net docs](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just to know, it seems that if an imgur image can't be found from a link, that link will always load a custom image with the message:

```
the image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available.
```

So, if the image can't be found, it will be replaced with the custom image from imgur.

**The problem starts when the image is no longer available, can't be loaded or something else happen and then you will get the typical broken image like this:**

[image]

**Code:**

Well, to solve this problem, I made this example for you:

*(I am assuming that for getting imgur images you are downloading the source code from the imgur user and then recover all image links and put them in array. That's why I am starting at that point)*

```
<?php
/* Array with Imgur images */
$imgArray = array('http://i.imgur.com/Uqotub.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/kPQFgb.jpg', 
'http://i.imgur.com/7teVGb.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/lnCZIb.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/sn6Ayb.jpg');

/* Imgur custom 404 image */
$customImg = 'http://i.imgur.com/404.jpg';

/* Do a loop for your images, if a valid image was found and loaded, 
 * you will have the following array from imgData: 
 * Array ( [0] => 160 [1] => 160 [2] => 2 [3] => width="160" height="160" [bits] => 8 [channels] => 3 [mime] => image/jpeg )
 */
foreach ($imgArray as $index => $value) {

    $imgData = getimagesize($value);

    /* if $imgData is an array means that image loaded ok */
    if(is_array($imgData)) {
        echo '<img src="'.$value.'"/>';
    /* else $imgData is nothing because image is broken or not available, 
     * now you pass the custom image */
    } else {
        echo '<img src="'.$customImg.'"/>';
    }
}
?>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**PS.** Your question is not clear to me. So, if you are trying to check if an image is the same or something else you can do what Nikola K. answered in his/her post.

Hope this helps :-)